# Can included file script be viewed in the file in which it is included?

Tags: php, php-include

I am creating a web application in php. In order to provide security to the code, I am writing database connection and other confidential scripts in a file called `functions.php`.

And i am hosting this file on my server at `example.com/functions.php`.

In my clients application(which is an external site-`example2.com`), i will simply include my `functions.php` file which is on my server as

```
include 'example.com/functions.php';
```

Is there any way so that the client can hack and view the code in functions.php file which is on my server ?

If yes, How ? and what are the measures to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way your client could see a code of a php executed script. As a further measure i recommend you use ioncube or similar file encrypting services if you are to distribute( not just include) your code to clients. Your client must have certain settigns enabled on the server, like allow_url_include, which in turn requires allow_url_fopen to be on. Most of the time these will be off for security reasons.

Comment: how to enable `allow_url_include` settings and turn on `allow_url_fopen`  ?

Comment: `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen` are not required to use protected code, and they are best kept off for security reasons.

Comment: Don't enable `allow_url_`. You can't change these settings from your script, they are `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`, meaning they can only be changed from php.ini

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is a server side script and can't be viewed from the client side.

**But**

that does not prevent you from being hacked or attacked. 
Gurus always find their way to reach your files or database if you are not careful.

**SO WHAT SHOULD I DO**.

Do your best to implement highly security measures to your website such as.

encryption, installing SSL certificates, using strong passwords, Not storing passwords on browsers and much more

some usefull resourse: [10 security tips to protect your website from hackers](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/website-security-tips-protect-your-site-7122853)

Comment: `foo.php.jpg` rather than `foo.jpg.php` is the double extension flaw in Apache, but some good points in that link none the less. The solution of serving file contents through a script can be effective but is one that is often screwed up by the typical developer, giving themselves an arbitrary file reading vulnerability. Using systems that block unexpected code such as ioncube24, systems to keep a site updated such as patchman plus basic vulnerability scanners, are the types of defenses one should be using in the war against malware. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Comment: @Nick that is a very good approach. i have researched on ioncube and i will explore more

Answer (score 0):

Only JavaScript and HTML codes are viewable by users. Php codes are not, so don't worry.

Comment: Unless your server is mistakenly configured to map `.phps` to the PHP source viewer or misconfigured in some other way as happened to facebook back in 2007. http://techcrunch.com/2007/08/11/facebook-source-code-leaked/

Comment: @Nick Well, no one can help if those kind of things happen. You might as well said, what happens if a hacker hacks your server, then they would be able to view your php codes. What I meant was, that, by default, no one should be able to view your php codes.